# Как через Guzzle заполнить форму с другого сайта и получить результат?

Tags: php, post, guzzle

Учусь работать с Guzzle. Сделал для себя небольшое упражнение.

Допустим, на стороннем сайте есть [форма с method="post"](http://hometask.std-221.ist.mospolytech.ru/term2/php/test1/index.php):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пользователь заполняет единственное поле с name="title", нажимает кнопку — сайт перебрасывает его на *result.php*, даёт ответ:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как [на моём сайте](http://booksearcher.std-221.ist.mospolytech.ru) программно заполнить эту форму и получить ответ?

Делаю следующим кодом, но post-параметр не передаётся. Как исправить?

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Подключаем класс Client
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
// Подключаем класс Request
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;

// Инициализируем класс для работы с удаленными веб ресурсами
$client = new Client();

// Инициализируем класс для работы с удаленным веб ресурсом
$request = new Request('POST', 'http://hometask.std-221.ist.mospolytech.ru/term2/php/test1/result.php', [
    'title' => 'Дубровский'
]);

// Задаем анонимную функцию, которая будет обрабатывать ответ сервера
$promise = $client->sendAsync($request)->then(function ($response) {
    echo $response->getBody();
});

// Запускаем соединение с удаленным ресурсом и передаем управление по обработке ответа анонимной функции
$promise->wait();
```

Comment: Для этого проинспектируй форму на другом сайте, посмотри, какие параметры принимает и куда их отправляет. Формируешь POST объект и отправляешь на удаленный обработчик. Соответственным образом получаешь ответ и выдешь его на своем фронте result.php

Comment: Проинспектировал форму, написал код — не работает. Добавил в вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

У меня было две ошибки.

Первая — не занёс поля формы в массив form_params.

Вторая — использовал класс Request, который был в коде, скопированном [с какого-то сайта](http://tceburashka.com/guzzle/).

**Рабочий код упражнения полностью**

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Подключаем класс Client
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

// Инициализируем класс для работы с удаленными веб-ресурсами
$client = new Client();

// Делаем запрос, получаем ответ
$response = $client->request('POST', 'http://hometask.std-221.ist.mospolytech.ru/term2/php/test1/result.php', [
    'form_params' => [
        'title' => 'Дубровский'
    ]
]);

// Выводим ответ
echo $response->getBody();
```